# Concurrent cache using WeakReference's throws an NPE

Tags: java, concurrency, nullpointerexception, garbage-collection, weak-references

I need a concurrent cache of objects where each instance wraps a unique `id` (and maybe some extra information, which is omitted for simplicity in the code fragment below) and no more objects can be created than the number of corresponding ids,

**and**

I also need the objects to be GC'ed as soon as no other object references them (i. e. keep the memory foorprint as low as possible), so I want to use `WeakReference`'s, not `SoftReference`'s.

In the below example of a factory method, `T` is not a generic type -- instead, it can be thought of as some arbitrary class with an `id` field of type `String`, where all ids are unique. Each value (of type `Reference<T>`) is mapped to the corresponding `id`:

```
static final ConcurrentMap<String, WeakReference<T>> INSTANCES = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@NotNull
public static T from(@NotNull final String id) {
  final AtomicReference<T> instanceRef = new AtomicReference<>();

  final T newInstance = new T(id);
  INSTANCES.putIfAbsent(id, new WeakReference<>(newInstance));

  /*
   * At this point, the mapping is guaranteed to exist.
   */
  INSTANCES.computeIfPresent(id, (k, ref) -> {
    final T oldInstance = ref.get();
    if (oldInstance == null) {
      /*
       * The object referenced by ref has been GC'ed.
       */
      instanceRef.set(newInstance);
      return new WeakReference<>(newInstance);
    }

    instanceRef.set(oldInstance);
    return ref;
  });

  return instanceRef.get();
}
```

The subject of `WeakReference`'s needing to be GC'ed once they're cleared (i. e. the referrant object GC'ed) is out of scope of this question -- in the production code, this is implemented using reference queues.

`AtomicReference` is used solely for the purpose of returning a value from outside the lambda (which is executed in the same thread as the factory method itself).

---

Now, the question.

After a couple of weeks of the code running successfully, I've received an `NPE` which originates from the extra `null` checks IntelliJ IDEA added thanks to `@NotNull` annotations:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/example/T.from must not return null

In practice, this means that `instanceRef` value wasn't set in either of the branches, or the whole `computeIfPresent(...)` method wasn't called.

The only possiblity for a race condition I see is the map entry being removed (from a separate thread processing reference queues to GC'ed instances) somewhere between `putIfAbsent(...)` and `computeIfPresent(...)` calls.

Is there any extra room for a race condition I am missing?

Comment: Not quite certain where your code issue is but the problem you have is you have forgotten that GC can happen at any time - e.g. after your `computeIfPresent` but before your `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remember that not only can other threads be happening but also GC. Consider this fragment:

```
  instanceRef.set(oldInstance);
  return ref;
});
// Here!!!!!
return instanceRef.get();
```

What do you think would be the effect if a GC kicked in at the `Here` point?

I suspect your fault is in the `@NotNull` because this method *can* return `null`.

### Added - Logic

If the final `instanceRef.get()` is returning `null` (as is implied) then the following statements can be made.

1. The key **was** present and the `oldInstance` had been GCd. A certainly non-null `newInstance` is recorded.

   ```
   // This line MUST be executed.
   instanceRef.set(newInstance);
   ```
2. The key **was** present and the `oldInstance` had **not** been GCd. A certainly non-null `oldInstance` is recorded.

   ```
   // This line MUST be executed.
   instanceRef.set(oldInstance);
   ```
3. The key **was NOT** present.

Therefore the problem could occur when the instance is present when `putIfAbsent` is called but gone by the time `computeIfPresent` is executed. This scenario could occur if an item is deleted between the `putIfAbsent` and the `computeIfPresent`. However, finding a route that returns `null` when no deletion is occuring is difficult.

### Possible Solution

You could, perhaps, ensure that the item being referenced is **always** recorded in the reference.

```
@NotNull
public static Thing fromMe(@NotNull final String id) {
    // Keep track of the thing I've created (if any)
    // Use AtomicReference as a mutable final.
    // NB: Also delays GC as a hard reference is held.
    final AtomicReference<Thing> thing = new AtomicReference<>();
    // Make the map entry if not exists.
    INSTANCES.computeIfAbsent(id,
            // New one only made if not present.
            r -> new WeakReference<>(newThing(thing, id)));

    // Grab it - whatever it's contents.
    // NB: Parallel deletions will cause a NPE here.
    trackThing(thing, INSTANCES.get(id).get());
    // Has it been GC'd
    if (thing.get() == null) {
        // Make it again!
        INSTANCES.put(id, new WeakReference<>(newThing(thing, id)));
    }

    return thing.get();
}

// Makes a new Thing - keeping track of the new one in the reference.
static Thing newThing(AtomicReference<Thing> thing, String id) {
    // Make the new Thing.
    return trackThing(thing, new Thing(id));
}

// Tracks the Thing in the Atomic.
static Thing trackThing(AtomicReference<Thing> thing, Thing it) {
    // Keep track of it.
    thing.set(it);
    return it;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the code example, `instanceRef` is an `AtomicReference<T>` , *not* a `WeakReference<T>` nor an `AtomicReference<WeakReference<T>>`, so the target `instanceRef` is pointing to can't be GC'ed until the scope is exited. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Bass - You are correct - I will dig further but I believe it must be an unexcpected GC.

Comment: @Bass - Is there any way you are deleting entries from the map? That could cause this under rare conditions.

Comment: Yes, there is. It's mentioned in the last paragraph of my question (removal from a reference queue which results in a `ConcurrentMap.remove()` call). The question is whether there's any *other* way a race condition can occur.

Comment: The original race condition turned out to be easily detectable with [JCStress](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jcstress/), the issue becoming even more vivid if `Thread.yield()` is injected between `Map::putIfAbsent` and `Map::computeIfPresent` calls. A combination of the above two calls can be made atomic if a single `Map::compute` is used instead.